# How to show users nearby in order to add them?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, beacon

I would like a flutter app to show the user other app users nearby in order to add them. I know this feature is often solved with bluetooth but I can't figure out to implement this functionality in flutter.
My main problem with the [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) package is that you first have to pair the devices in order to transmit user data (e.g. a 20 character long firebase userID) and this is getting out of hand if many app users are nearby and you first have to connect to each one of them in order to get the user information.

Therefore I was looking for some kind of advertising functionality and came across beacons. I've setup the beacons [broadcasting](https://pub.dev/packages/beacon_broadcast) and [ranging](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beacon) package. Unfortunately, ranging has to scan for a specific UUID on iOS in order to find the beacon. So there are only the minor and major values left to transmit some sort of custom user information. But these are both limited to 16bits. So I can't even advertise the firebase userId (20 bytes) to users nearby.

At the moment the only solution which comes to my mind is to temporarily store a combination of minor and major value in Firestore for a specific user. So other users can look up the beacon related user data there and add the user. But I am pretty sure and hope there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the beacon_broadcast plugin says that it uses the iBeacon or AltBeacon format (depending on platform). Jos Ryke did a [tweet](https://twitter.com/josryke/status/627851131046219776) showing a beacon cheat sheet with these formats on there:

[image]

As the flutter plugin doesn't allow free form access to setting the advertising data, you might need to be a little creative. If you add up the Beacon UUID, Major, and Minor fields it comes to 20 bytes. You could split your value between the three fields and then reconstruct the single value at the other end.

There appear to be other plugins that give you access to the full manufacturer data:
https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth/example

```js
  _startScan() {
    _scanSubscription = _flutterBlue
        .scan(
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      /*withServices: [
          Uuid.fromString('0000180F-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB')
        ]*/
    )
        .listen((scanResult) {
      print('localName: ${scanResult.advertisementData.localName}');
      print(
          'manufacturerData: ${scanResult.advertisementData.manufacturerData}');
      print('serviceData: ${scanResult.advertisementData.serviceData}');
      setState(() {
        scanResults[scanResult.device.id] = scanResult;
      });
    }, onDone: _stopScan);

    setState(() {
      isScanning = true;
    });
  }
```

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ble_peripheral/example

```js
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  FlutterBlePeripheral blePeripheral = FlutterBlePeripheral();
  AdvertiseData _data = AdvertiseData();
  bool _isBroadcasting = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      _data.includeDeviceName = false;
      _data.uuid = 'bf27730d-860a-4e09-889c-2d8b6a9e0fe7';
      _data.manufacturerId = 1234;
      _data.manufacturerData = [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    });
    initPlatformState();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! That's exactly what I was trying ... using these three fields to advertise at least the userId. But as I mentioned in my question: The UUID has to be one specific ID which the beacon scanner has to look for on iOS. So this has to be the same for every device. And the minor and major value are to small to send any user information.